# Julia Marker Width or Weight

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Julia 1.5

Plots.jl

Default backend - I haven't changed the backend so it should be GKS, right?

I've got the idea of marker size down, color, and opacity down. I'm trying to change the *weight* of the individual markers. I'm using the :x symbol. I want to make it appear bold.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no built-in default for doing that, but you can make your own marker shape and then modify its thickness yourself, e.g., with

```
rotate90((x, y)) = (-y, x) # function to rotate a tuple by 90 degrees
function mymarker(t=0.1) # t = relative thickness (default 0.1)
    tip0 = (1.0, 1.0)
    tips = [tip0, rotate90(tip0), -1 .* tip0, -1 .* rotate90(tip0)]
    out = reduce(vcat, [tip .- t .* rotate90(tip), tip .+ t .* rotate90(tip), t .* tip .+ t .* rotate90(tip)] for tip in tips)
    push!(out, out[1])
end
```

and then chose the relative thickness `t` and do something like,

```
plot(your_data..., marker = (Shape(mymarker(t)), 30, RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.2)))
```

Example in a Pluto notebook:

[image]